# How to add position of a string in a list to a new list of doubles?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, count, position

Example:

r is a textfile loaded in a list

```
r = ['John is american', 'Bea is french', 'John is american', 'Ray is german', 'John is american', 'Bea is french', 'Bea is french', '', 'Lisa is dutch']
```

What I want to do is to count the number of occurrences and to add the position in r:

```
finallist = ['string', frequency, [positions in r]]

finallist = [['John is american', 3, [0,2,4]], ['Bea is french', 3, [1,5,6]], ['Ray is german', 1, [3]], ['Lisa is dutch', 1, [7]]]
```

I know how to count the strings in r:

```
[[x,r.count(x)] for x in set(r)]
```

(or using Counter class from the collections library)

but how can I add the position of the strings in r to finallist?

Comment: Does the output order of the sentences in `finallist` matter?

Comment: (in my answer the output happens to match your expected output only because I used Python 3.6, where the `dict` builtin now maintains insertion order).

Comment: Also, `'Lisa is dutch'` appears in position 8, not 7, because there is an empty element at 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to track the positions of the sentences (building lists); the final lengths of these lists are also the frequency count:

```
from collections import defaultdict

pos = defaultdict(list)
for i, sentence in enumerate(r):
    pos[sentence].append(i)
finallist = [[sentence, len(positions), positions] for sentence, positions in pos.items()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> r = ['John is american', 'Bea is french', 'John is american', 'Ray is german', 'John is american', 'Bea is french', 'Bea is french', '', 'Lisa is dutch']
>>> pos = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, sentence in enumerate(r):
...     pos[sentence].append(i)
...
>>> [[sentence, len(positions), positions] for sentence, positions in pos.items()]
[['John is american', 3, [0, 2, 4]], ['Bea is french', 3, [1, 5, 6]], ['Ray is german', 1, [3]], ['', 1, [7]], ['Lisa is dutch', 1, [8]]]
```

If output order matters, and you don't yet have access to Python 3.6 (which is [in beta](https://www.python.org/download/pre-releases/) at the time of this answer but whose `dict` implementation preserves insertion order), then you could use an `OrderedDict` instance, and use `dict.setdefault()` to materialise the initial empty list for each key:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

pos = OrderedDict()
for i, sentence in enumerate(r):
    pos.setdefault(sentence, []).append(i)
finallist = [[sentence, len(positions), positions] for sentence, positions in pos.items()]
```

Comment: Wow what a nice solution. :) I forgot to write that I don't want to consider the empty lines or lines with only spaces. Is it faster to remove the empty lines from the list `output` or to add an empty string check in the `for loop`?

Comment: @Reman: depends. What position does `'Lisa is dutch'` have, 7 or 8?

Comment: @Reman: if the answer is '8', then simply add `if sentence:` in the loop to filter out empty sentences. If it is `7`, you need to first filter out the empty strings or keep a counter manually (`i = 0` outside the loop, inside the loop use the above `if` test and if the sentence is not empty use `i += 1` before appending).

Comment: Martijn, the answer is '8'. I'll add `if sentence:`. Thanks for your help and your great answer. :)